# React - can I find out if a component is currently visible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When using react, i have components that change on the page depending on what route the user navigates to, is there a way to detect if a component is currently showing?
for example when the user is on any page that is not the home page, the "go home" button will show, but i want to remove it when the user navigates back to the home page (its not quite that simple but that is the general idea)

Comment: Which component are you checking for visibility in your example? I think you're over thinking this.. have different components for different routes and only write in the components you want to be in each one. If you want to conditionally display something use a boolean.

Comment: i have a component called header which is displayed at the top of every route, it has 3 buttons nested in it but on the home page i would prefer it just display 2 of the 3

Comment: `{ !location.pathname.includes('/home') && <NotShowingOnHome /> }`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your buttons are already child components, if they have been passed event handlers. Perhaps it's time to flesh them out a little.

```
class GoHome extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  state = {
    visible: "shown"
  }
  // While the code here would execute just prior to render,
  // which I assume would happen during page load and after url change,
  // you could place it in a function the serves as a callback
  // to any route change event.
  componentWillMount = () => {
    // Please check this regex.
    var re = /\/home/i;
    if (re.test(window.location.href)) {
      this.setState({
        visible: "not-shown"
      });
    };
  }
  // Using Google's Material Icons as an example.
  render () {
    let myClass = "material-icons " + {this.state.visible};
    return (
      <i className={myClass}>home</i>
    )
  }
}
```

CSS classes.

```
.shown {
  display: block; // Or inline-block, what-have-you.
}

.not-shown {
  display: none;
}
```

Essentially, the CSS class of the button will be different depending on the current browser URL.